# A game of blackjack with guaranteed 50 50 win loss

Tags: probability

Suppose you are playing 2 hands of blackjack at the same time and the dealer guarantees if you lose hand A they will pay whatever you bet for hand B but if you win hand A you automatically lose hand B. Can you find a way to mathematically prove a way to win instead of continuing even money? Let's say you only brought $2000 to the casino this night!

```
Hand A     Hand B 
  W          L
  W          L
  L          W
  W          L
  W          L
```

Comment: What are the pay-out rates? And which simplified set of rules do you use? And can you still win with hand B in case you lose with hand A?

Comment: Betting $A$ dollars on the first hand and $B$ dollars on the second hand is the same as betting $A-B$ dollars only on the first hand. Clearly this cannot be used to guarantee a money win.

Comment: Carry on smiling what it ensures is that you will not have 2 continuous losing strings!

Comment: You need to put @ before the username to get the user notified of the comment.

Comment: Hetebrij all even money and if you lose hand a you automatically win hand B

Comment: So, bet \$1 on hand A, play to lose, then bet \$1999 on hand B? Although I'm not sure what "they will pay whatever you bet for hand B" means, exactly. Also, I squared up your table but I don't understand what it signifies.

Comment: @joffan if you do that and a wins you will win 1$ and lose $1999

Comment: @Triumph I'm not the dealer - I can always take another card :-)

Comment: @Joffan, if hand A is dealt a blackjack, the rules might stipulate an automatic payout.  It would help if the OP specified the rules more precisely.  In general it seems clear that one should play hand A to lose a small amount, with a heavy bet on hand B.

Answer (score 1):

A complete answer depends on the exact rules for the game, but here is one possibility.

One (old) set of rules for blackjack stipulates an automatic 3:2 payout on a blackjack -- e.g., a \$1 bet wins \$1.50.  In that case, betting \$800 on hand A and \$1200 on hand B produces a profit of \$400 by intentionally losing hand A if it isn't a blackjack (assuming you can continue to "hit" even if your card count reaches 21, which, of course, one would ordinarily never do) and neither profit nor loss if hand A is a blackjack (i.e., you win \$1200 for the blackjack but automatically lose your hand B bet).  In general, betting $40\%$ of your money on hand A and $60\%$ on hand B will never lose money and usually make money.

The one caveat here is that the OP doesn't specify what happens in the result of a tie, which in particular occurs when both the player (specifically hand A) *and* the dealer have blackjack.  In normal play, hand A would neither win nor lose, while hand B cannot win and can only avoid losing by also starting at blackjack.  But if we assume a dealer-hand-A blackjack tie is an overall tie, then the strategy described above *guarantees* the player will never lose (and will eventually get banned from the casino).

Remark:  Since blackjacks are relatively rare, one can probably accelerate the average rate of return by reserve a small amount of money and betting heavily with the rest on hand B, for hand A to lose -- e.g., putting \$2 on hand A and \$1993 on hand B for the first round, holding onto \$5 in case hand A "wins" \$3 with blackjack, which would leave you with \$10 for the next round (after which you could play the conservative guaranteed strategy until you've recouped enough to bet heavily on hand B again.)  It might be worth looking into what the optimal no-risk betting strategy is, if the OP clarifies the exact rules, especially regarding ties, but also regarding blackjack payouts and minimum/maximum bets.